# Run Putty command from python

Tags: python, bash, shell, putty

I currently have a .sh file from which I run a command called `metl`.
metl is a python package which helps with the extraction, transformation and loading of data from almost any source.

The normal procedure I need in the putty console and works fine is the following:

```
metl -m migration.pickle1 
     -t migration.pickle2 
     -s filename.csv 
     config_file.yml
```

The procedure that I run from my .sh file, and also works properly is the following:

```
metl -m migrationfiles/"${migbefore}" \
    -t migrationfiles/"${migafter}" \
    -s "${y}" \
    config_file.yml
```

Sorry I was not clear enough before, in general I want to run a Python script from the PuTTY console, and from inside this Python script I need to run a PuTTY command, which is the one I mentioned before `(metl -m migration.pickle1....)`

So what I am trying to run is this:

```
import os

os.system("metl -m " + path + ""\"" + migbefore + "-t " + path + ""\"" + migafter + "-s " + csvfile + " " + directory + ""\"" + config_file.yml)
```

Comment: What does this have to do with PuTTY? Also, please include the problematic code, the command you use to run it, what it does, and how that differs from what you expect it to do.

Comment: Try to remove all `""\""`  substrings from your code (you don't need it). But if you need to put `"\"`, use `"\\"` instead of `""\""`.

Comment: Also `config_file.yml` must be in quotes. Just put quotes correctly to solve close this problem.

Comment: I tried also this solution and worked out perfectly, I managed to solve the problem correcting the quotation marks of the statement, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use:

```
import subprocess
proc_args = ['metl', '-m', 'arg2', ....]
process = subprocess.Popen(proc_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```